# Active Directory LDAP Query by sAMAccountName and Domain

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

How do you do a query of an LDAP store by sAMAccountName and Domain?  What is the "domain" property named in Active Directory or LDAP terms?

This is what I have for the filter so far. I'd like to be able to add in the domain:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=BTYNDALL))
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, modify your search filter to only look for users and not contacts:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=BTYNDALL))
```

You can enumerate all of the domains of a forest by connecting to the configuration partition and enumerating all the entries in the partitions container.  Sorry I don't have any C# code right now but here is some vbscript code I've used in the past:

```
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
AdComm.Properties("Sort on") = "name"
AdComm.CommandText = "<LDAP://cn=Partitions," & _
    objRootDSE.Get("ConfigurationNamingContext") & ">;" & _
        "(&(objectcategory=crossRef)(systemFlags=3));" & _
            "name,nCName,dnsRoot;onelevel"
set AdRs = AdComm.Execute
```

From that you can retrieve the name and dnsRoot of each partition:

```
AdRs.MoveFirst
With AdRs
  While Not .EOF
    dnsRoot = .Fields("dnsRoot")

    Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = dnsRoot(0)
    objOption.Value = "LDAP://" & dnsRoot(0) & "/" & .Fields("nCName").Value
    Domain.Add(objOption)
    .MoveNext 
  Wend 
End With
```

Comment: The 'With' and 'While' statements look hideous.  I think I wrote this a long time ago and haven't needed to update it since it just worked...

Answer (score 17):

You can use following queries

Users whose Logon Name(Pre-Windows 2000) is equal to **John**

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(sAMAccountName=**John**))
```

All Users

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370))
```

Enabled Users

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

Disabled Users

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

LockedOut Users

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(lockouttime>=1))
```

Comment: how do I search for multiple sAMAccountName ?

Comment: Thanks! To get it to work in my application, I had to wrap anything after an `!` with parentheses: `...(!(sAMAccountType=805306370))...`

Answer (score 12):

The **best way** of searching for **users** is `(sAMAccountType=805306368)`.

Or for disabled users:

`(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`

Or for active users:

`(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))`

I find LDAP as not being so light at it was supposed to be.

Also resource for [common LDAP queries](http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109050000-famous-filters.htm) - trying to find them yourself and you will lose precious time and definitely make mistakes.

Regarding domains: it's not possible in a single query because the domain is part of the user `distinguisedName` (`DN`) which, on Microsoft AD, is not searchable by partial matching.

Answer (score 5):

"Domain" is not a property of an LDAP object. It is more like the name of the *database* the object is stored in.

So you have to connect to the right database (in LDAP terms: *"bind to the domain/directory server"*) in order to perform a search in that database.

Once you bound successfully, your query in it's current shape is all you need.

BTW: Choosing `"ObjectCategory=Person"` over `"ObjectClass=user"` was a good decision. In AD, the former is an "indexed property" with excellent performance, the latter is not indexed and a tad slower.

Comment: For querying of Users in AD I like to use sAMAccountType=805306368 as this narrows your search specifically and is fast

Answer (score 3):

You have to perform your search in the domain:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677934(VS.85).aspx
So, basically your should bind to a domain in order to search inside this domain.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET, use the [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) class. You can pass in your domain as a string into the constructor.

```cs
// if you domain is domain.com...
string username = "user"
string domain = "LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com";
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(domain);
search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
```

Comment: So lets say my login is COMPANY\BTYNDALL how do I just assume that the LDAP string is going to be LDAP://DC=company,DC=com because in my case this would be wrong the last DC is DC=net. Is there any way to lookup "short domains" in AD and get the longer LDAP one?

Comment: or do I just have to build a lookup table in my app?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a C# class incorporating

- the algorithm from Dscoduc,
- the query optimization from sorin,
- a cache for the domain to server mapping, and
- a method to search for an account name in DOMAIN\sAMAccountName format.

However, it is not Site-aware.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public static class ADUserFinder
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _dictDomain2LDAPPath;

    private static Dictionary<string, string> DictDomain2LDAPPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _dictDomain2LDAPPath)
            {
                string configContainer;
                using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE"))
                    configContainer = rootDSE.Properties["ConfigurationNamingContext"].Value.ToString();

                using (DirectoryEntry partitionsContainer = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Partitions," + configContainer))
                using (DirectorySearcher dsPartitions = new DirectorySearcher(
                        partitionsContainer,
                        "(&(objectcategory=crossRef)(systemFlags=3))",
                        new string[] { "name", "nCName", "dnsRoot" },
                        SearchScope.OneLevel
                    ))
                using (SearchResultCollection srcPartitions = dsPartitions.FindAll())
                {
                    _dictDomain2LDAPPath = srcPartitions.OfType<SearchResult>()
                        .ToDictionary(
                        result => result.Properties["name"][0].ToString(), // the DOMAIN part
                        result => $"LDAP://{result.Properties["dnsRoot"][0]}/{result.Properties["nCName"][0]}"
                    );
                }
            }

            return _dictDomain2LDAPPath;
        }
    }
    
    private static DirectoryEntry FindRootEntry(string domainPart)
    {
        if (DictDomain2LDAPPath.ContainsKey(domainPart))
            return new DirectoryEntry(DictDomain2LDAPPath[domainPart]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException($"Domain \"{domainPart}\" is unknown in Active Directory");
    }

    public static DirectoryEntry FindUser(string domain, string sAMAccountName)
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry rootEntryForDomain = FindRootEntry(domain))
        using (DirectorySearcher dsUser = new DirectorySearcher(
                rootEntryForDomain,
                $"(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(sAMAccountName={EscapeLdapSearchFilter(sAMAccountName)}))" // magic number 805306368 means "user objects", it's more efficient than (objectClass=user)
            ))
            return dsUser.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
    }

    public static DirectoryEntry FindUser(string domainBackslashSAMAccountName)
    {
        string[] domainAndsAMAccountName = domainBackslashSAMAccountName.Split('\\');
        if (domainAndsAMAccountName.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException($"User name \"{domainBackslashSAMAccountName}\" is not in correct format DOMAIN\\SAMACCOUNTNAME", "DomainBackslashSAMAccountName");

        string domain = domainAndsAMAccountName[0];
        string sAMAccountName = domainAndsAMAccountName[1];

        return FindUser(domain, sAMAccountName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Escapes the LDAP search filter to prevent LDAP injection attacks.
    /// Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649149/how-to-escape-a-string-in-c-for-use-in-an-ldap-query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchFilter">The search filter.</param>
    /// <see cref="https://blogs.oracle.com/shankar/entry/what_is_ldap_injection" />
    /// <see cref="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475.aspx" />
    /// <returns>The escaped search filter.</returns>
    private static string EscapeLdapSearchFilter(string searchFilter)
    {
        StringBuilder escape = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchFilter.Length; ++i)
        {
            char current = searchFilter[i];
            switch (current)
            {
                case '\\':
                    escape.Append(@"\5c");
                    break;
                case '*':
                    escape.Append(@"\2a");
                    break;
                case '(':
                    escape.Append(@"\28");
                    break;
                case ')':
                    escape.Append(@"\29");
                    break;
                case '\u0000':
                    escape.Append(@"\00");
                    break;
                case '/':
                    escape.Append(@"\2f");
                    break;
                default:
                    escape.Append(current);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return escape.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is a hidden gem. I realize credit is due @Dscoduc, but I had no patience to translate that Visual Basic.