# Search a LDAP group name that contains extra Closed Bracket

Tags: c#, ldap

So in the Active Directory there is a group name that contains an extra Close Bracket:

> i.e: My Group Name (Something))

In my piece of code, here is how I search it:

```
string searchCN = "My Group Name (Something))";
dirSearch.Filter = string.Format("(|(&(objectCategory=group)(CN={0}*)))", searchCN);
dirSearch.PropertyNamesOnly = false;
dirSearch.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.None;
searchcCollection = dirSearch.FindAll();
```

So then, because of the extra closed bracket, the search it became invalid and throw an exception.

**Is there a way I can search this properly?**

I tried to add escape character \ infront each of the Open Bracket and Close Bracket, although the search is valid, but its returns no result from the search.

And Note: If I search with `string searchCN = "My Group Name (Something)";` , I can get the result, because its match everythings after the first Closed Bracket....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Special Characters. If any of the
> following special characters must appear in the search filter as
> literals, they must be replaced by the listed escape sequence.
>
> ASCII character   Escape sequence substitute:
>
> - `*`   \2a
> - (     \28
> - )     \29
> - \     \5c
> - NUL   \00
> - /     \2f

Here you have the code to perform escape: https://stackoverflow.com/a/694915/986161

Comment: Yes, this, I saw the Java version, but I thought is simply means "\" + (char)28, so I only put escape key as "\\(", didn't know it actually needs to be "\28".... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your LDAP search filters should always be [RFC 4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515) compliant.  Please take a look at Section 3 (pp.3-4) of the RFC page for more details on what characters and how they should be escaped.