# How to prevent LDAP injection when using DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, code-injection

This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649149/how-to-escape-a-string-in-c-for-use-in-an-ldap-query) but the answers are out-dated and I would like to know what the modern approach is.

I have some C# code to search Active Directory for an employee with employeeid `id` which is a string that maybe came from a web form or something and can't be fully trusted.

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry());
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(employeeid=" + id + "))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephonenumber");
SearchResult sresult = search.FindOne();
```

as you can see, it would not be too hard to enter an `id` value that would do things I don't really intend it to do. [OWASP considers this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/LDAP_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to be a serious vulnerability. What is the best modern approach to prevent this?

I would prefer not to have my own code [like this](http://[HemoncPatientsOriginalAddress]) that manually replaces specific characters, if there is an alternative library function that is being actively maintained.

Best solution I've seen anywhere is using the `AntiXSS` library:

```
string encoded = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.LdapFilterEncode(id);
```

But [it appears](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpl) that this library is no longer being maintained:

> AntiXSS is now End of Life
>   In .NET 4.0 a version of AntiXSS was included in the framework and
>   could be enabled via configuration. In ASP.NET v5 a white list based
>   encoder will be the only encoder.
>   As such the standalone versions of AntiXSS should be considered end of life.
>   The source and installers will remain online allow people using
>   earlier versions of .NET to enable an alternative, whitelist based
>   encoded but no further enhancements, outside of security fixes, will
>   be made.

Lots of answers point to [`LinqtoAD`](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpl) which sure sounds like a great approach, but unfortunately doesn't sound like it was ever production-ready:

> Disclaimer
>   This project is meant as a basic sample on implementing custom LINQ
>   query providers. It hasn't been tested thoroughly and we do not
>   provide any support whatsoever. Do not use it in a production
>   environment without proper testing and validation of the technology's
>   behavior. Users are most welcome to report issues and bugs through the
>   Issue Tracker on this site.

What is the modern approach? Is there anything in the newer versions of .Net framework to mitigate LDAP injection?