# Auto-create DC= fields for LDAP from domain or subdomain

Tags: for-loop, awk, sed, ldap, subdomain

Via BASH script, I'm automatically constructing a string like: `DC=us,DC=earth,DC=com` for [LDAP domain components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325738/). But, *I won't know how many subdomain **components** a domain might have*.

For example:

- `dub.sub.domain.tld` needs `DC=dub,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=tld`
- `sub.domain.tld` needs `DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=tld`
- `domain.tld` needs `DC=domain,DC=tld`

But, I don't know which one I'll have, and I need to automatically create this string.

My current solution is:

```bash
# The variable we got somehow
indomain="dub.sub.domain.tld"

#IFS='.' #Please no, sed instead...
# Create a loopable list with space as the IFS
domaincomponents=$(echo $indomain | sed 's/\./ /g')

# Process each domain component
finalstring=""
for component in $domaincomponents; do
  finalstring=DC=$component,$finalstring
done

# Remove the trailing ,
finalstring=$(echo $finalstring | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /')
```

Result: `$finalstring` = `DC=tld,DC=domain,DC=sub,DC=dub`

...which is in reverse

---

Not only does this produce the string backwards; it seems over-processed and that a tool like `awk` could do a cleaner job.

Is there a better way?

*I am assuming that `DC=` in LDAP can go as deep as any subdomain name; correct me if I'm wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
echo 'dub.sub.domain.tld' | sed 's/^/DC=/; s/\./,DC=/g'
```

Output:

```
DC=dub,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=tld
```

Comment: `sed` is more elegant here; `awk` works well, but needs more code

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
dub.sub.domain.tld
sub.domain.tld
domain.tld
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";OFS=",DC="}{$1="DC="$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
DC=dub,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=tld
DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=tld
DC=domain,DC=tld
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is dot and output field separator is `,DC=`, then for each line I prepend 1st field with `DC=` which also causes line rebuilt and `print` such changed line. If you want to know more about `FS` or `OFS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Or `echo dub.sub.domain.tld | awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";OFS=",DC="}{$1="DC="$1;print}'